# Indicator functions, $I_A=\sum_i I_{A\cap B_i}$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

In my textbook it says something I don't quite understand regarding indicator functions:
$$I_A(\omega)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} 1 &\mbox{if}& \omega\in A \\ 0&\mbox{if}& \omega\notin A\end{array} \\  \right.$$

Then, suppose:
$ \{B_i: i\in I\} $ is a family of disjoint evens with $A\subseteq \bigcup_{i \in I} B_i$ then:
$$I_A=\sum_i I_{A\cap B_i}$$

I don't understand this at all, we're saying that A is a subset of the union of $B_i$, that's as far as I get it. As I understand it, the indicator function can be 1 or 0, so what does it mean when $I_A$ is the sum of the indicator functions of the intersections of A and $B_i$? If anyone can explain this with an example I'd be very grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: Ok, changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given identity means for every $x$,
$$I_A(x) = \sum_i I_{A\cap B_i}(x).$$

Let's look at it case by case. If $I_A(x) = 0$ then $x \not\in A \implies x \not\in A\cap B_i$, so $I_{A\cap B_i} = 0$. Clearly, both sides of the sum are zero.

If $I_A(x) = 1$ then $x \in A \implies x \in \cup_i B_i$ (as $A \subseteq \cup_i B_i$). So $x$ must be one of $B_i$'s, say in $B_j$. But if $x$ is in $B_j$ it cannot be in any $B_i$'s when $i \neq j$ (as $B_i's$ are disjoint). Thus, $I_{A\cap B_i} = 0$ unless $i = j$ in which case it is $1$. On the RHS, you are adding up one $1$ and a bunch of $0$'s, thus both sides give $1$.